# How to list only cell scoped datasource in websphere application server using wsadmin/jython scripting?

Tags: python, jython, websphere-8

I want to list only cell scoped data source by using the jython script.
currently i can list down all the data source which is giving me cluster scoped and cell scoped both, but i am not able to segregate them.

I am using the below command to listing the datasource.

AdminConfig.list('DataSource',AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:mycell/')).splitlines()

output of this command is all the available datasources for specific cell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list off all data sources that are cell scoped you will likely need to iterate through all cells like this:

```
cells = AdminConfig.list('Cell').split()
datasources = []
for cell in cells:
    cn = AdminConfig.showAttribute(cell, 'name')
    print cn
    datasources.append(AdminConfig.list('DataSource',cell).splitlines())
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for response, i just tried the above code but its giving me output like this: cellName  None

Comment: i have stored this datasources.append(AdminConfig.list('DataSource',cell).splitlines()) in variable and print, output is None. but i am not able to list down only cell scoped datasources.